# How do I access INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES on a specific database

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm trying to get a list of databases on my server whose database contains the table "Foobar".  The snag I'm running into is that I can't figure out how to use @CurrDB in conjunction with INFORMATION_SCHEMA.  Any suggestions?

```
DECLARE @CurrDB varchar(255)
DECLARE RecSet CURSOR FOR
Select [name] FROM master..sysdatabases
OPEN RecSet

Fetch NEXT FROM RecSet Into @CurrDB

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)   
BEGIN 
    Fetch NEXT FROM RecSet Into @CurrDB
    IF (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @CurrDB..INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Foobar')) 
    BEGIN 
        print @CurrDB
        --do other stuff
    END 
END

Close RecSet
DEALLOCATE RecSet
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
sp_msforeachdb 'SELECT ''?'' As DatabaseName 
                FROM   [?].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
                WHERE  TABLE_Name = ''foobar'''
```

You could also use the following code to fill a table variable with a list of database names.

```
Declare @DatabaseList Table(DatabaseName VarChar(200))

insert Into @DatabaseList
Exec sp_msforeachdb 'If Exists(SELECT ''?'' As DatabaseName 
                FROM   [?].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
                WHERE  TABLE_Name = ''YourTableNameHere'') Select ''?'''

Select * From @DatabaseList
```

Answer (score 0):

Following stored procedure displays all the database and table as per parameter passed to this sp.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Usp_findtablenameinalldatabase @TableName VARCHAR(256) 
AS 
    DECLARE @DBName VARCHAR(256) 
    DECLARE @varSQL VARCHAR(512) 
    DECLARE @getDBName CURSOR 

    SET @getDBName = CURSOR 
    FOR SELECT name 
        FROM   sys.databases 

    CREATE TABLE #tmptable 
      ( 
         DBName     VARCHAR(256), 
         SchemaName VARCHAR(256), 
         TableName  VARCHAR(256) 
      ) 

    OPEN @getDBName 

    FETCH next FROM @getDBName INTO @DBName 

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
      BEGIN 
          SET @varSQL = 'USE ' + @DBName + '; INSERT INTO #TmpTable SELECT ''' + @DBName + 
          ''' AS DBName, SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS SchemaName, name AS TableName FROM sys.tables WHERE name LIKE ''%' 
          + @TableName + 
                        '%''' 

          EXEC (@varSQL) 

          FETCH next FROM @getDBName INTO @DBName 
      END 

    CLOSE @getDBName 

    DEALLOCATE @getDBName 

    SELECT * 
    FROM   #tmptable 

    DROP TABLE #tmptable 

go
```

How to call this sp:

```
EXEC usp_FindTableNameInAllDatabase 'TableName'
```